# How to show only the string and not URI in SPARQL query result?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Having the following query, I desire to show only "Jorge Glas"

```
prefix dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
prefix dbpedia:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT str(?leader) as ?label
WHERE {
dbpedia:Ecuador dbpedia-owl:leader ?leader
}
```

[image: I desire to show only "Jorge Glas"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.  One is to use SPARQL REPLACE to get the string you want:

```
REPLACE(?leader, "^.*/", "")
```

That gets you "Jorge_Glas", then you can do the same to replace the underscore with a space:

```
REPLACE(?x, "_", " ")
```

However, this is not how you should use DBPedia resources.  Most DBPedia resources have an rdfs:label that will give you the desired name result in multiple languages.  So a first step is to find out what DBPedia has on these resources through an exploratory query:

```
SELECT (str(?leader) as ?label) ?p ?o
WHERE {
   dbpedia:Ecuador dbpedia-owl:leader ?leader .
   ?leader ?p ?o
}
```

You'll find that the matches for ?leader have rdfs:label properties in multiple languages.  To get the English label, use the following:

```
SELECT ?leaderName
WHERE {
   dbpedia:Ecuador dbpedia-owl:leader ?leader .
   ?leader rdfs:label ?leaderName .
   FILTER (lang(?leaderName) = "en")
}
```

Comment: **replace** is useful, but in a case like this where the prefix send to always be the same, **strafter** Can suffice, as in the older, essentially the same, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479394/why-my-sparql-query-return-uri-of-a-class-instead-of-its-name?lq=1.

Comment: strafter() would be more performant if the prefix is known for all results.  if this isn't the case a regex solution can be use.