# URI sparql to specific individuals

Tags: java, uri, sparql

I'm trying to get the name of the individuals of a specific type so that i get them in a list for later use . 
I tried this and the result is in the form of an URI . 
How o I get for example for

```
( ?name = <http://www.semanticweb.org/muna/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-9#Boucles_geometrique> )

Boucles geometrique  //as it is the name of the individual .
```

That is what I tried 
and it dont work .

```
String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "

                + "PREFIX S: <http://www.semanticweb.org/muna/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-9#> " +

        " SELECT ?name {?name rdf:type S:Mode } ";
```

Knowing that those individuals , have "HasName" data property .

Comment: I told you in your previous question that this was already asked and answered here. Next time, please use the search! Topic will be closed. And for your case, add another triple pattern that retrieves the `hasName` value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my SPARQL query return the URI of a resource instead of its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479394/why-does-my-sparql-query-return-the-uri-of-a-resource-instead-of-its-name)

Comment: @AKSW I used the search and I have tried it all , I'm using jena for a model , and extracting information from an ontology not dbpedia , and it didnt work .

Comment: @AKSW and I knew how to add the triple pattern to reteive the Hasname  value , I would not have asked the question I guess .

Comment: Adding a triple pattern is just reading any SPARQL tutorial...`SELECT ?name {?s rdf:type S:Mode . ?s S:HasName ?name }`

Comment: @AKSW  Thank You , it has worked now